# Save file using VueJS and Electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I want to save and load JSON from a file which is allocated to my local storage.

Its my first project using Electron.

This is my current code and I get this error. `fs.readFileSync is not a function`

```js
<script>
import timer from "./components/Timer"
import fs from "fs"

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    timer
  },
  data() {
    console.log(fs.readFileSync("timer.json"))
    return {
      timerOptions: null
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.timerOptions = fs.readFileSync("./timer.json") // Here I want to load Data, but get the Error
    console.log(this.timerOptions)
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: This looks like client-side, in-browser code. There's no "fs" available there. You need to do these operations in main.js instead, afaik

Comment: Yes, VueJS is client side. But Electron is like an Desktop app, so it must be possible somehow.

Comment: It's possible of course, but you need to do it in the main process, then send the result to the client side: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-main

Comment: If I did this, how can I access the data? Its my first time I work with electron

Comment: What do you mean by "access the data"? Inside Vue? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: Where am I stuck? Yes.
I dont know exacly where. I dont even know how I have to start...

I'm totally confused.
the ipc is the "background.js" right? 
First: Which event should I hook to execute my file Loading
Second: How tf can I refer the JSON data from the background.json to the timerOptions in my App.vue.

Comment: In my electron example app there's a `main.js`. This is the main app script which creates the Chromium window and tells it to load your index.html. In this script, which has access to `fs` you need to send data to the in-browser script. Example here: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/web-contents#contentssendchannel-args

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the main process write your save to file function as:

```
import { ipcMain } from 'electron';
import fs from 'fs';

ipcMain.handle('export-file', async (event, {data}) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const stream = fs.createWriteStream(filePath, {
      encoding: 'utf-8',
    });
  ... save the data here
})
```

Then call it from your Vue component as:

```
<script>
import { ipcRenderer } from 'electron';

export default {
  name: 'SaveFileComponent',

  methods: {
    async save() {
      const data = {}; // load it from your source            
      await ipcRenderer.invoke('export-file', {data});
    }
 }
}
</script>
```